# Using javascript generated from mindscape web workbench (coffeescript source) in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This coffee script code

```
    class TestCoffee
        constructor: (@saludo) ->

    helloCoffee: ->
        alert @saludo+" Coffee v7"
```

is generating the following javascript with mindscape web workbench 2.0.332.18684

```
    (function() {
        var TestCoffee;
        TestCoffee = (function() {
          function TestCoffee(saludo) {
            this.saludo = saludo;
          }
          TestCoffee.prototype.helloCoffee = function() {
            return alert(this.saludo + " Coffee v7");
          };
          return TestCoffee;
        })();
    }).call(this);
```

How should I use this code inside my asp.net mvc 3 view?

I'm importing the js code with

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/helloCoffe.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and trying to use with

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var coffee;

        coffee = TestCoffee("Jelouuuu");

        coffee.helloCoffee();

    });

</script>
```

I got a TestCoffee undefined error

So, how should I use it?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design:

> Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all
>   CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  (function(){
>   ... })(); This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation
>   of the var keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the
>   global namespace by accident.
>
> If you'd like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use,
>   attach them as properties on window, or on the exports object in
>   CommonJS. The existential operator (covered below), gives you a
>   reliable way to figure out where to add them; if you're targeting both
>   CommonJS and the browser: exports ? this

http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

I normally use jQuery $.extend to push a function into the jquery namespace for other scripts to use.

IE:

file1.coffee

```
$ ->
    $.extend
        ErrorAlert: (text) ->
            simpleGritter $("#SuccessGritter"), text
            return false
```

file2.coffee

```
$ ->
    $("#right").ajaxError (event, request, settings) ->
        $.ErrorAlert("Some kind of bad thing happened at: " + settings.url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple changes will allow this to work.  Add a '@' symbol to your class declaration:

```
class @TestCoffee
    constructor: (@saludo) ->

    helloCoffee: ->
        alert @saludo+" Coffee v7"
```

And change the way you instantiate your class.  Use a 'new' on your class

```
coffee = new TestCoffee("Jelouuuu");
```

That should get you what you want.